# Log Entry View and other settings pages don't load (5.18.4, Drupal 7.67)

Tags: drupal, logs

recently I am unable to load Log Entry Views and other settings pages in my Drupal CiviCRM. On the page it shows the following errors:

Warning: include(/var/www/html/sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/de_DE//%%48/488/4880C3C4%%LogViewEntry.tpl.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in include() (Zeile 1911 von /var/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/Smarty/Smarty.class.php).

Warning: include(): Failed opening '/var/www/html/sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/de_DE//%%48/488/4880C3C4%%LogViewEntry.tpl.php' for inclusion (include_path='/var/www/html/sites/default/files/civicrm/ext/uk.artfulrobot.civicrm.importhelper/:/var/www/html/sites/default/files/civicrm/ext/ca.bidon.civiexportexcel/:/var/www/html/sites/default/files/civicrm/ext/ca.civicrm.logviewer/:/var/www/html/sites/default/files/civicrm/ext/com.agiliway.civimobileapi/:.:/var/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm:/var/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages:.:/var/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm:/var/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages:/var/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/tecnickcom:/var/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/phpseclib/phpseclib/phpseclib:/var/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear_exception:/var/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/pear/auth_sasl:/var/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/pear/log:/var/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/pear/console_getopt:/var/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src:/var/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/pear/mail:/var/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/pear/net_socket:/var/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/pear/net_smtp:/var/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/pear/validate_finance_creditcard:.:/usr/share/php') in include() (Zeile 1911 von /var/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/Smarty/Smarty.class.php).

The last major change to my CRM was adding the civicrm.importhelper extension.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Exchange!  I'm tempted to mark this question as a duplicate to point you to existing answers - but I'm struggling to find the "one true answer". [templates_c cache files not being deleted](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/18930/templates-c-cache-files-not-being-deleted) is close.  Essentially, it sounds like something created a file in `templates_c` that's not readable by the web server user.  The quick solution is to delete the `templates_c` folder - this is always safe and it will regenerate.  However, in the longer term you need to find what caused the problem.  Are you running cron as a user other than the web server/PHP user?  Are you running `drush` from the command line as a user with different permissions?  If you don't find the solution the problem will keep coming back.