# CIVICRM_TEMPLATE_COMPILEDIR / template_c folder becomes too large. How to empty it periodically?

Tags: smarty, scheduled-job, templates, cache

We realized that the folder which is set in CIVICRM_TEMPLATE_COMPILEDIR (in our case as per default: template_c) became way too large. From time to time it grew so much that we needed to empty it manually. How can this directory be emptied on a periodic basis?

Answer (score 3):

The action Job.cleanup has a parameter tplCache which is set to 0 by default. When the action is called with the parameter set to 1 the folder gets emptied.

1. Create a new scheduled job
2. Choose "Job" as API call and cleanup as action
3. In the parameter textfield add tplCache=1

We chose monthly as the run frequency but this depends on your project.